# setSelected a specific jradiobutton in a buttongroup based on action command

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

i want to setSelected a speicfic jradiobutton in a buttongroup based on the actionCommand(/name of the specific jradiobutton).

it could  be done usind .setSelected(true)

for example,

```
JRadioButton rabbitButton = new JRadioButton("rabbit");
 rabbitButton .setActionCommand("rabbit");
JRadioButton pigButton = new JRadioButton("pig");
 pigButton .setActionCommand("pig");

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

group.add(rabbitButton);
group.add(pigButton);
```

now.. without ,

{ rabbitButton.setSelected(true);}  NOR  {group.setSelected(rabbitButton.getModel,true)}

is there a way to setSelected(true) rabbitButton based on the action command()?

Comment: did you forget the homework tag :-)

Comment: @kleopatra  No!  It's a management system for Old McDonald's farm!

Answer (score 6):

```
yourButtonGroup.clearSelection();
yourRadioButton.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a small method that allow me to set any radio group button. Very convenient if you don't want to use if for any radio button.

```
public void setButtonGroup(String rdValue, Enumeration elements ){
    while (elements.hasMoreElements()){
        AbstractButton button = (AbstractButton)elements.nextElement();
        if(button.getActionCommand().equals(rdValue)){
            button.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
setButtonGroup(yourValue, yourButtonGroup.getElements());
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`ButtonGroup#getElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#getElements%28%29) method gives you an enumeration of `AbstractButton` instances. The [`AbstractButton#getActionCommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getActionCommand%28%29) allows you to retrieve the action command and the [`AbstractButton#getSelected`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected%28boolean%29) allows you to alter the selection.

So there is a way, but you will have to loop over the enumeration yourself.