# how to select a radiobutton in buttongroup in Java

Tags: java, buttongroup

I created several radio buttons in a button group but I cannot understand how to set necessary radio button in a code. My program reads the personal information in a file and shows it in the form (one person at a time). The personal information includes a marital status apart from name and other data, so I use radio buttons for the marital status.

This is my code (I used class Person with `public enum MaritalStatus {SINGLE, MARRIED, WIDOW};`):

```
buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            for (Person.MaritalStatus c : Person.MaritalStatus.values()) {
                    JRadioButton radioButton = new JRadioButton(c.name());
                    buttonGroup.add(radioButton);
        if (c == mStatus) {
                        radioButton.setSelected(true);
                    }
        radioButtonPanel.add(radioButton);
            }
```

So, I have a group of radio buttons:

```
SINGLE, MARRIED, WIDOW
```

If user changes the person, the program must update the info about the marital status of the next person in a file. In other words, I don't know how to choose necessary radio button. The method of button group `setSelected(buttonModel, bool)` requires the buttonModel/radioButton name, but I don't have it in the code

Comment: addActionListener -> when happens update the file with the new status

Comment: u should do that in the action listener of the button that u clicked to change the user

Comment: maybe this helpful for u  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/65223-dynamic-radio-buttons-in-button-group/

Comment: How and when is `mStatus` status updated?  Maybe a short runnable example might help

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875674/setselected-a-specific-jradiobutton-in-a-buttongroup-based-on-action-command